# Speech-to-text on Apple Watch

Tags: watchos-2, dialogflow-es, google-voice

We are struggling implementing the Dialogflow conversational API to an Apple Watch.

We have done an implementation but can not manage the speech regognition to work (via Google Voice API) because the encodings are different (FLAC vs.provided LPCM).

Any suggestions on how to perform a speedy speech-to-text with custom phrases (e.g. custom words, suggestions etc...) on the Apple Watch?

Comment: You may want to post your question in the Dialogflow enterprise Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/dialogflow-enterprise-edition-users